# Regular expressions in Databricks Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Curious thing.  Using Databricks, but getting two different behaviors when using the replace_regex functionality.

```
%sql
select upper(regexp_replace('Test (PA) (1234) ', '[(]\\d+[)]', '')) as result
```

returns my expectation:
TEST (PA)

Yet:

```
%python    
display(spark.sql("""select upper(regexp_replace('Test (PA) (1234) ', '[(]\\d+[)]', '')) as result"""))
```

returns:
TEST (PA) (1234)

Should these not be equivalent in the two different contexts (spark sql, and spark / python / pyspark)? Why doesn't the second context work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't take into account character escaping rules.  In Python your `\\` is converted into a single `\`, so your regex changes to `[(]\d+[)]`. You have choice:

- use raw string `r"""select upper(regexp_replace('Test (PA) (1234) ', '[(]\\d+[)]', '')) as result"""`
- double backslashes: `[(]\\\\d+[)]`

with any of these changes, it produces correct result